# AJAXToolkit Dynamically Hide a tab?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know how to hide a tab:

```
MyTabContainerID.Tabs[1].Visible = false;
```

That works.  What I'm having trouble with is changing the visibility of a tab triggered by the postback of a radioButtonList selectedIndexChanged event.

By the time the page reaches my selectedIndexChanged event handler the tab has already loaded Visible=True from the ViewState.  I can change it to false all day long in my selectedIndexChanged event, it won't hide the tab b/c it's already loaded.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblMyRadioButtonList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblMyRadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged">                                                        
<asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False"></asp:ListItem>
```

**ASCX**

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MyTabContainerID.Tabs[1].Visible = Tab1Visibility;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        common.alert("Error in PageName.Page_Init.<br>ERROR=" + ex.Message);
    }
}
protected void rblMyRadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {       
        Tab1Visibility = Convert.ToBoolean(((RadioButtonList)sender).SelectedValue);
        MyTabContainerID.Tabs[1].Visible = Tab1Visibility;  //BY THE TIME THIS HAPPENS IT'S ALREADY ON THE PAGE WITH VISIBLE=TRUE                   
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        common.alert("Error in PageName.rblMyRadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged.<br>ERROR=" + ex.Message);
    }
}

protected bool Tab1Visibility
{
    get { return (bool)Session["ses_bTab1Visibility"]; }
    set { Session["ses_bTab1Visibility"] = value; }
}
```

Thoughts?  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

***.ASPX**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disableTab1() {
            $find('<%=MyTabContainer.ClientID%>').get_tabs()[1].set_enabled(false);
        }
    function enableTab1() {
        $find('<%=MyTabContainer.ClientID%>').get_tabs()[1].set_enabled(true);
    }
</script>

<!--THESE RADIOBUTTONS LEVERAGE THE TAB CONTAINER'S CLIENTSIDE set_enabled METHOD
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblMyRadioButtonList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True" Selected="True" onClick="enableTab1();"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False" onClick="disableTab1();"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

***.ASCX on Page_Load**

```
//I RUN A SQL QUERY TO DETERMINE WHETHER OR NOT TO DISABLE TAB1 HERE 
//IF IT SHOULD BE DISABLED I REGISTER THIS STARTUP SCRIPT
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
Type cstype = this.GetType();
String csScriptName = "Tab1_Visibility";
if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csScriptName))
{
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), csScriptName, "setTimeout(function() { disableTab1()}, 0);", true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the Visibility of your tab control in the  `rblMyRadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged` method. Even though the tab control's state will have been loaded from the ViewState at this point it can still be overridden.

I had a similair problem where Visibilty just couldn't be set. It was driving me mad. The solution was that the visiblility was being explicitly set in a **container (parent) control**. This will override the setting for the child control. Could that be your issue.

Other than that then do the usual. Breakpoint on `rblMyRadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged` and watch values. Also - can you manually force the Visibility on `Page_PreRender` - which is further downstream still.

**EDIT**

The other thing that could affect it is update panels. If the radiobutton list is in an update panel and the tab is outside of it then the update wouldn't work as the part of the page with the tab wouldn't be refreshed.

Comment: Not only is the tab visibility getting set to False in my selectedIndexChanged event, per your suggestion I set it again in the Page_PreRender.  The tab is still visible when the page loads.

If I set the tab's visibility to False when !IsPostBack, that works.  But, when setting visibility on PostBack I get no joy.

Comment: It might be worth noting the page hierarchy:  Page > TabContainer > TabPanel > FormView > RadioButtonList

Comment: Ahhh...your edit makes some sense...that could very well be the issue...I'll have to look into that some more.